# How to generate PDF/UA files? Or convert them from HTML?

Tags: html, linux, pdf, accessibility

PDF/UA is a standard for accessible PDF documents. They're also called "tagged PDF's" because they are built using styled tags (like "heading 1") instead of just having a bigger font for headings. This helps in making the document accessible for people with disabilities (such as blind people) who use assistive technology to help them read the file.

I would like to generate such files on my Linux server. Preferably in PHP by converting an accessible HTML document to PDF/UA, but any method that works will do as long as it runs on Linux.

Does anyone know any solution for this? Converting from HTML would be nice because that already would be a tagged document, but I could also settle for putting together the document in a script myself as long as the output is an accessible PDF.

Comment: The only product I know that would do this is iText. I have seen a few sample files here on SO. They *are* tagged, but they are not tagged to PDF/UA standards. I don't know if this is a shortcomming of the source file, iText or the user doesn't know how to properly tag. I know the iText creator is on SO, and comments periodically.

Comment: In the meantime I've encountered [PDFLib](http://pdflib.com) which seems to do the job. The examples they provide for PDF/UA are pretty good and their API gives me enough flexibility to create the documents I need.

It's a bit pricy, but so is iText.

If anyone has any other suggestions, please let me know! I'm really amazed there aren't that many PDF/UA generators out there, especially since converting a tagged document from HTML (which is already tagged by nature) seems like such a natural thing to me.

Comment: PD4ML starting from v4 can convert HTML/CSS to a tagged PDF/UA, conforms the Matterhorn Protocol: https://pd4ml.tech/pdf-ua/  It can be used as a Java library or as a standalone command line tool.